# Identity of a thread

Tags: .net, multithreading, identity

Assume Net process `P` runs under windows account `A1`. I assume if thread ( running within `P` ) is running under some other identity ( obtained via `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` ) than `A1`, it still has the same rights as `A1` when accessing system resources ( such as files etc )?

thank you

Comment: threads don't run within each other!

Comment: I didn't imply thread was running within another thread. I said thread was running within a process ( or to be more exact...thread is running within an application domain hosted by process P)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not expect a thread that has a different identity to "inherit" the permissions from the process identity.

Just to be sure I ran an impersonation test .Using the sample here [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx) I ran the following code on a different thread.

```
  WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle());
  Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(newId);
  string foo = System.IO.File.ReadAllText (@"test.txt");
  Console.WriteLine(foo);
```

Even though the ID of the process has rights to read test.txt it if the newID doesn't it fails.